# How to determine the maximum number of simultaneous connections for a given `HttpClient` instance

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a `Servlet` that builds an `HttpClient` instance when it starts.
It shares this client with a collaborating module used when servicing requests.
I would like to use the [`FutureRequestExecutionService`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-dev/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/FutureRequestExecutionService.html) API within
the collaborating module to easily send some requests concurrently.
This requires using an `HttpClient` instance along with an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) instance. The [tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/advanced.html#d5e936) recommends setting the `ExecutorService` to use the same number of threads as the `HttpClient`'s maximum number of concurrent connections.

> The constructor for the futureRequestExecutionService takes any existing httpClient instance and an ExecutorService instance. When configuring both, **it is important to align the maximum number of connections with the number of threads you are going to use.** When there are more threads than connections, the connections may start timing out because there are no available connections. When there are more connections than threads, the futureRequestExecutionService will not use all of them.

I thought that the collaborating module should be the one creating the `ExecutorService` for its concurrent requests. The problem in that case is that the collaborating module does not necessarily know how many threads it should be using since it doesn't know how many simultaneous connections the `HttpClient` has been configured to allow.

I know I could use `HttpClient`'s `getConnectionManager` method, but as of 4.3 this is deprecated. So then what is the recommended way of ascertaining how many simultaneous connections a given `HttpClient` will allow? I suspect that the wrong answer is to save a reference to the `ConnectionManager` object used to build the `HttpClient` and pass it along with the collaborating module or to define some kind of global constant. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question.

Perhaps I should instead create the `HttpClient`, `ExecutorService`, and `FutureRequestExecutionService` objects all at the same time and then pass just the
`FutureRequestExecutionService` instance to the modules that want to make HTTP requests
using a shared client. I'd like to do this in a manner that is consistent with the intent of the authors of HttpClient; I'm just not sure in this case what that is exactly.

**EDIT:** To clarify, the `HttpClient` instance is created using an `HttpClientBuilder` that has a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` set for its connection manager.
However, this does not happen in the same scope as the creation of the `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` and `FutureRequestExecutionService`.
I am starting to suspect that they should be created together and then instead of passing the `HttpClient` instance around, use the `FutureRequestExecutionService` instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main point here is to avoid situations when too many worker threads end up contending for too few connections thus causing a performance bottleneck. The number of worker threads and connections per route / total limits just need to be about reasonable: say, 12 workers and 10 connections or 10 workers and 12 connections but not like 12 workers and 2 connections.

Having said all that, to answer your question I would not recommend tightly coupling of `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` and the `FutureRequestExecutionService` wiring code. To me a better approach should be having a simple POJO or even a hash map representing HTTP service configuration that all your wiring code should depend upon instead of direct coupling of various implementation classes.

Something along this line

```
static class MyHttpServiceConfig {
    int workerNum = 10;
};

MyHttpServiceConfig config = new MyHttpServiceConfig();

CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
        .setMaxConnPerRoute(config.workerNum)
        .build();

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(config.workerNum);

FutureRequestExecutionService executionService = new FutureRequestExecutionService(
         client, executor);
```

Comment: Wow, I can hardly believe I got an answer from the project lead himself! I will give this a try (and will probably accept your answer shortly thereafter). Thanks for your many contributions to the Apache HttpComponents project.

Comment: BTW, I know that a POJO is a "Plain Old Java Object" but what do you mean by "or a man"?

Comment: @iX3: please excuse my spelling. Corrected.

Comment: no problem, please excuse my lacking sufficient Java experience to figure out that you were probably talking about a map :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.html) to control the max number of httpClient connection can be used at the same time. And then you can pass in the httpClient you create with this connection manager into the FutureRequestExecutionService constructor.

An example is also provided by apache [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e380).

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question. I am actually using  `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` already. The problem is that the `HttpClient` & `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` are created in one class and the `ExecutorService` is created in another.