# Why shouldn't I use a PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager with FutureRequestExecutionService?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x, executorservice

I'm writing a service which needs to run many parallel http requests.  It will be deployed in an auto-scaling environment too but I'd like to get as much performance out of each service instance as I can.

I came across this post [How to determine the maximum number of simultaneous connections for a given `HttpClient` instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014919/how-to-determine-the-maximum-number-of-simultaneous-connections-for-a-given-htt/19024759#19024759) and noticed the recommendation to not mix these two classes.

I'm curious as to why.  Basically, I'd like to submit http client jobs to an executor service and I want http connection pooling in place to reuse http connections.  Perhaps, I'm over-thinking this but I don't see why it's a bad idea to combine these two classes/concepts in one application.

Also, I noticed that example give in that response uses one http client instance per FutureRequestExecutionService. . . which makes me a bit nervous but CloseableHttpClient is thread safe so perhaps I'm worrying needlessly.

Also, for most of the client tasks my code submits, I don't care if the response is 200 and if it's not, I'm just planning to increment an error tracking metric and possibly log the exception, so I'm thinking of going the callback route.  On that note, it's not clear to me where the callback will run.  If my threadpool thread runs and completes i.e. doesn't block on the http request futures. . . then what thread runs the callback code?

Answer (score 1):

The post in question advises against "... tight coupling of PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and the FutureRequestExecutionService wiring code ...". There is no reason to NOT use `FutureRequestExecutionService` with `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`.

Comment: Oh hey, I was hoping you'd answer @oleg, thanks!  Great, any thoughts about my callback approach?  Most of the time, I will only care and only write a log message when a request receives a 40x or 50x response.